# Using many Shiny inputId's, create a data frame where the columns have the inputId as name, and the input value as value

Tags: r, shiny

The use case is to shorten something like below. Is this even possible?

```
  row_to_add <- data.frame(
  work_order = input$work_order,
  date = input$date, 
  res_or_camp = input$res_or_camp,
  building = input$building,
  room = input$room,
  issue = input$issue,
  trade_responsible = input$trade_responsible,
  trade_attended = input$trade_attended,
  staff_called = input$staff_called,
  staff_attended_1 = input$staff_attended_1,
  staff_attended_1_type = input$staff_attended_1_type,
  staff_attended_2 = input$staff_attended_2,
  staff_attended_2_type = input$staff_attended_2_type,
  contractor = input$contractor
  )
```

Reprex below (in this case, it cannot be minimal):

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
tbl_colnames <- c("work_order", "date", "location", "building", "room", "issue", "trade_responsible",
                  "trade_attended", "staff_called", "staff_attended_1", "staff_attended_1_type", "staff_attended_2", 
                  "staff_attended_2_type", "contractor")

inputs <- tagList(
  map(
    .x = tbl_colnames,
    .f = function(inputId) {
    radioButtons(inputId = inputId, label = inputId, choices = letters[1:4], inline = TRUE)
    }))


ui <- page_sidebar(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 5),
  title = "My Shiny Data entry app",
  sidebar = sidebar(
    width = 270,
    title = "Information",
    inputs,
    actionButton("update", "Enter entry")
    ),
  card(
    tableOutput("tableDT"),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ## Initialize empty data.frame
  df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(tbl_colnames))) 
  colnames(df) <- tbl_colnames
  .data <- reactiveVal(df)
  
  observe({
    row_to_add <- data.frame(
      work_order = input$work_order,
      date = input$date, 
      res_or_camp = input$res_or_camp,
      building = input$building,
      room = input$room,
      issue = input$issue,
      trade_responsible = input$trade_responsible,
      trade_attended = input$trade_attended,
      staff_called = input$staff_called,
      staff_attended_1 = input$staff_attended_1,
      staff_attended_1_type = input$staff_attended_1_type,
      staff_attended_2 = input$staff_attended_2,
      staff_attended_2_type = input$staff_attended_2_type,
      contractor = input$contractor
    )
    
    new.data <- rbind(.data(), row_to_add) # adding new data
    .data(new.data) # updating data
    
  }) |> 
    bindEvent(input$update)
  
  output$tableDT <- renderTable(
    .data()
  )
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Ignore:
Stack overflow takes issue with most of the post being code................................................................................................................................

Comment: Use [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).  Or tidy your data.  The suffices in your column names indicate that your data frame is not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) right now.  Also, remember that you maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Your first two suggestions don't relate to the question. Data is fine as is. Reprex added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(reactable)
library(purrr)


ui = fluidPage(
  
  div(style = "padding: 1rem; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; gap: 1rem; place-items: center;",
      
      map(
        .x = c("work_order", "date", "time", "res_or_camp", "building", "room", 
               "issue", "trade_responsible", "trade_attended", "staff_called", 
               "staff_attended_1", "staff_attended_1_type", "staff_attended_2", 
               "staff_attended_2_type", "contractor"),
        .f = function(inputId) {
          
          div(radioButtons(inputId = inputId, label = inputId, choices = letters[1:4], inline = TRUE))
          
        })),
  
  div(reactableOutput(outputId = "table"))
  
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  df = reactive({
    
    map(
    .x = c("work_order", "date", "time", "res_or_camp", "building", "room", 
           "issue", "trade_responsible", "trade_attended", "staff_called", 
           "staff_attended_1", "staff_attended_1_type", "staff_attended_2", 
           "staff_attended_2_type", "contractor"),
    
    .f = function(inputId) {
      
      set_names(x = input[[inputId]], nm = inputId)
      
    }) %>% flatten_df()
  })
  
  output$table = renderReactable({ reactable(data = df()) })
  
  
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(port = 3838, host = '0.0.0.0'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reprex. In your example, I'm looking to shorten the reactive `df` to say 2 lines of code. I'm just wondering if there's any way to use `map()` here, just as you used `map()` in the ui assignment.

Comment: see updated version. Ok, i see u got another solution as well :-)

Comment: Thanks! `flatten_df()` or now `list_rbind()` is safer so I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In shiny, input is simply a named list. And using global assignment we can do:

```
row_to_add <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = length(tbl_colnames))) 
colnames(row_to_add) <- tbl_colnames
walk(tbl_colnames, \(x) row_to_add[[x]] <<- input[[x]])
```